# Is it safe to use overleaf.com for research articles?

Tags: publications, research-process

Is it safe to use overleaf.com for writing research articles? Some springer.com journals provide a template. The submission is also easy by clicking "submit".

Comment: Safe in what way? Do you have a particular concern about its potential unsafeness?

Comment: Safe in a way that no one else is able to read my paper besides the journal editors/reviewers it is intended for.

Comment: @scaaahu, you are right but some springer journals have started pointing to overleaf templates. Moreover, I cannot find the springer's svjour3 template since this morning.

Comment: Okay. I got it. By reading [this Springer web page](http://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/journal-author/overleaf), I guess it's safe because Springer actually has partnered with Overleaf. Let's wait for others who have experience to tell us more.

Comment: The link to LATEX files is available on springer's site. Thanks for your help.